# Angularjs dependency injection not working

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I've just installed a fresh install of `Angular 2`. But when I try to inject a service called `TestService` into a login `component` like this:

**LoginComponent:**

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  template: `
      {{ test.test }}
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('test') private test){};
}
```

**App**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import {TestService} from "./test.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: 'test', useClass:TestService}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**TestService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  test = 'test';
  constructor() { }
}
```

I receive an error:

```
error_handler.js:47EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:25 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be related to the code in your question. Where and how do you use `name` in `AppComponent`?

Comment: Thanks had a mistake in ```AppComponent``` like you said.

Answer (score 3):

On view you should be using `Elvis Operator`. Just to make sure `test` property will ask on `test`. Currently when initial change detection occurs `test.test` tries to evaluate binding on view. Since initially `test` is undefined `test.test` fails.

```
{{ test?.test }}
```

Comment: AFAIK strings as provider keys are fine. Usually using `OpaqueToken` is a good idea but not mandatory.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for your headsup, I was totally on wrong track,  I can surely say that now. Its related to binding evaluation..

Comment: Sounds likely but I'm still missing information in the question where `name` is accessed that causes `Cannot read property 'name'`. If your suggestion is correct it would need to be `Cannot read property 'test'`, but I assume it's just inaccuracy in the code provided in the question.